# Can't freeze the terminal with the shortcut Ctrl+S on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I used to use the shortcut `Ctrl+s` to freeze the terminal output when a command is giving a fast output (it allows you to read what the command is giving), and unfreeze it after that using the shortcut `Ctrl+q`.

But this shortcut is no longer working on Ubuntu 17.04 , clicking on `Ctrl+s` only give me the output `^S`.

This is really driving me crazy, why on earth would Ubuntu devs disable this shortcut ?? and how am I suppose to make it work again ?

### Additional informations

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 with the desktop `budgie-desktop`, the terminal `terminix` (although I also tried this with `gnome-terminal`, and it isn't working neither), and the shell I am using is `fish shell` (although I tried also with `bash` and `zsh`, and it isn't working neither).

## EDIT

I can't believe this, it is actually the fish shell that is doing this. I tried on another machine with Ubuntu 17.04 with `zsh` as the default shell, and it is working just fine. Just when I install fish shell and call it, this error occurs.

I will try to find a solution and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperently, it is the `fish` shell which is disabling this feature. I asked on their github page how to enable it back, and they said :

> Currently, this isn't possible to change from your end. We just unconditionally disable it.

Here is the link for the issue https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/4168.